# Differential Protein Expression analysis - no significant differences

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to perform differential expression analysis for a set of proteins using limma. The two groups are "C" and "D", which are substrings from `colnames(mat)`. My output shows that there are no differential expression.

```
library(limma)

group <- factor(as.factor(gsub("_.*", "", colnames(mat))), levels=c("C", "D"))
design <- model.matrix(~ 1 + group)
colnames(design) <- c("C", "D")
contrasts <- makeContrasts(C - D, levels=colnames(design))
mat.log <- log2(mat)
mat <- na.omit(mat)
dge <- edgeR::DGEList(counts=mat, group=group)
keep <- edgeR::filterByExpr(dge)
v <- voom(mat, design, plot=TRUE)
vfit <- contrasts.fit(lmFit(v, design), contrasts=contrasts)
efit <- eBayes(vfit, proportion=0.1)
summary(decideTests(efit))
```

The purpose of running the differential expression analysis is to retrieve the samples that are "up" or "down". In my case, all of the expression are "NotSig", meaning I don't have a usable subset.

```
> summary(decideTests(efit))
       C - D
Down       0
NotSig  1725
Up         0
```

Data:

```
> dput(mat[1:10,])
structure(c(1.0275, 1.05, 0.55875, 0.78375, 0.7175, 0.76875, 
0.70875, 0.63, 0.73125, 0.76875, 0.8675, 0.74, 0.54875, 0.71375, 
0.6775, 0.64875, 0.61875, 0.63, 0.63125, 0.91875, 0.6775, 0.9, 
0.64875, 0.70375, 0.6975, 0.69875, 0.64875, 0.76, 0.65125, 0.82875, 
1.3075, 1.03, 0.81875, 1.06375, 0.8375, 0.91875, 0.99875, 1.03, 
0.98125, 1.05875, 0.7225, 0.89, 0.59125, 0.70625, 0.6925, 0.64125, 
0.63125, 0.64, 0.62875, 0.89125, 0.9625, 0.8, 0.60125, 0.77625, 
0.7325, 0.72125, 0.76125, 0.8, 0.75875, 0.78125, 1.2925, 1.05, 
0.75125, 0.91625, 0.8425, 0.86125, 0.86125, 0.83, 0.87875, 1.02125, 
0.9025, 0.98, 0.63125, 0.86625, 0.6625, 0.81125, 0.72125, 0.78, 
0.72875, 0.88125), dim = c(10L, 8L), dimnames = list(c("AAAS", 
"AAK1", "AAMDC", "AARS", "AASDHPPT", "ABCD3", "ABCE1", "ABCF1", 
"ABHD10", "ABI1"), c("C_1", "C_2", "C_3", "C_4", "D_5", "D_6", 
"D_7", "D_8")))
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this result is problematic?

Comment: @GregorThomas the purpose of running the differential expression analysis is to retrieve the samples that are "up" or "down". In my case, all of the expression are "NotSig", meaning I don't have a usable subset.

Comment: Your results could also mean that no samples are “up” and no samples are “down”. You need to explain why this can’t be the case in order to claim that there is a problem.

Comment: Any reasons why you're taking out the intercept? IMO it should be `model.matrix(~ 1 + group)` or short `model.matrix(~ group)`.